# momentjs - converting PM time string to moment is not working correctly

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to parse Time String to moment object, for AM string as '09:00 am' is working very well, but for PM string as '06:00 pm' it is not.

using this code:

```
moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Jerusalem');
moment.locale('he')

const momentObject1 = moment("09:00 am", "HH:mm a");
const momentObject2 = moment("06:00 pm", "HH:mm a");
```

**the 6 PM result is returned as AM**
[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use lowercase `hh` instead of uppercase `HH`

Comment: I tried and it didn't work, it is giving me the same exact result

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working:

```js
moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Jerusalem');
moment.locale('he')

console.log(moment("06:00 am", "hh:mm a").format())
console.log(moment("06:00 pm", "hh:mm a").format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.25/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey sir, thank you for your help, can check my question again please, I added a picture that shows exactly what I am getting as a result